# What are my audio devices?

Tags: sound

I'm attempting to use [easycap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easycapdc60/) to record from my camcorder but I'm having a slight problem. Using their [test script](http://dpaste.com/hold/327140/) I'm able to get audio and video. I've noticed that in the script on line 159 it makes a call to "`DEV_ADUIO`", which is reported as being "`plughw:2,0`".

Exactly what is this device? Is it located in `/dev/` somewhere?

I've done `ls /dev/` and I can't find anything that would suggest an audio device

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Run the command (in the terminal)

```
aplay -l
```

The output looks like

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC262 Analog [ALC262 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The device for this is **plughw:0,0**. The two zeros come from the **device 0** and **Subdevice #0**.

Comment: The problem with that is when I try to put plughw:2,0 (my audio device) into something like ffmpeg. I just get an error

Comment: Oh, these are in /dev/snd/

Comment: doesn't the 0:0 come from **card 0** and **device 0** ?

Answer (score 7):

Generally, there are a few ways to get audio playback and recording devices on Linux. I'm focusing on command-line tools in this answer.

## With PipeWire tools

If you are running [PipeWire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PipeWire) as your [sound server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_server), you can use [`pw-cli`](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_man_pw_cli_1.html) to get the names of all your inputs and outputs (recording and playback devices):

```
pw-cli list-objects | grep node.name
```

Example output:

```
node.name = "Dummy-Driver"
node.name = "Freewheel-Driver"
node.name = "Midi-Bridge"
node.name = "v4l2_input.pci-0000_00_1a.0-usb-0_1.6_1.0"
node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
node.name = "alsa_input.usb-UC_Mic_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback"
```

These node names can be used to [record audio from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1570333/how-can-i-record-audio-output-from-command-line-in-linux/1717767#1717767).

See also [`pw-link`](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_man_pw_link_1.html) which can list input and output PipeWire ports.

## With PulseAudio tools

Alternatively, you can use command-line tools that come with [PulseAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) (another sound server) to do the same:

```
pactl list | grep node.name
```

This produces similar output to `pw-cli list-objects` on my machine:

```
node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
node.name = "alsa_input.usb-UC_Mic_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback"
```

I found it useful to only display audio sinks, like loudspeakers and headphones:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Example output:

```
43  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
1076    alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_Wireless_Headset_4473D63ED97A-00.analog-stereo    PipeWire    s16le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
```

Mind that even if you use PipeWire as your audio server, [`pactl`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pactl.1) will probably still work since PipeWire aims to be a drop-in replacement for PulseAudio.

## With ALSA tools

As shown in [user4124's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22031/what-are-my-audio-devices#22036), you can list **playback** devices (e.g., headphones, loudspeakers) using [ALSA's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) command-line tools:

```
aplay --list-devices
```

Sample output for playback devices on my machine:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

For **recording** devices, use

```
arecord --list-devices
```

Sample output for recording devices on my machine:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

See also the `--list-pcms` option from [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay) to list all [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) devices.