# No sound on my Compaq CQ43

Tags: 10.04, sound

I'm new to linux. I've ubuntu 10.04LTS installed, but I'm not able to play any sound. I don't know how to install sound drivers on my machine.

Comment: Just a few questions first, why 10.04 and not 12.04LTS? Also, what [sound card](http://askubuntu.com/q/22031/12864), and what troubleshooting steps have you taken so far? Please edit your question so we can start helping you, as there isn't enough information there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sound drivers should be detected automatically by Ubuntu although sometimes one of the channels is muted which causes nothing to play...

Go into Terminal and type:   sudo apt-get pavucontrol

This will install a much better volume/sound manager that you can play with which will let you set up your sound driver a little easier...