# HDMI audio device not found anywhere. Please help

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi, intel, huawei

I have an Huawei Matebook 13 2019, running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Model wrt-wx9 in bios, says wrt-w19 on the laptop. GP108M [GeForce MX250] / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2).
The hdmi comes through a usb-c dongle.
Video shows good, but hdmi audio device is not listed.
The laptop has both intel and Nvidia gpus.
In ubuntu I'm using latest Nvidia recommended drivers, and prime-select nvidia. The same thing happens if I select intel.
Under windows the HDMI audio, shows as intel.
Tried different solutions after googling, but nothing is working.
Any suggestions?

Output of `pacmd list-cards`
`1 card(s) available. index: 0 name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3> driver: <module-alsa-card.c> owner module: 23 properties: alsa.card = "0" alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH" alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x9421c000 irq 145" alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel" device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3" sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0" device.bus = "pci" device.vendor.id = "8086" device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation" device.product.id = "9dc8" device.product.name = "Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller" device.form_factor = "internal" device.string = "0" device.description = "Innebygd lydenhet" module-udev-detect.discovered = "1" device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci" profiles: input:analog-stereo: Analog stereokanal inngang (priority 32833, available: unknown) output:analog-stereo: Analog stereokanal utgang (priority 39268, available: unknown) output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog stereodupleks (priority 39333, available: unknown) off: Av (priority 0, available: unknown) active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo> sinks: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#1: Innebygd lydenhet Analog stereokanal sources: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Innebygd lydenhet Analog stereokanal alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#2: Innebygd lydenhet Analog stereokanal ports: analog-input-internal-mic: Intern mikrofon (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown) properties: device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone" analog-input-headphone-mic: Mikrofon (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no) properties: device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone" analog-input-headset-mic: Hodetelefon-mikrofon (priority 8800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no) properties: device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone" analog-output-speaker: Høyttalere (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown) properties: device.icon_name = "audio-speakers" analog-output-headphones: Hodetelefoner (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no) properties: device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"`

Output of `aplay -l`
`**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

Comment: What are you attached to that you are trying to make the sound come out of?

Comment: https://consumer.huawei.com/en/accessories/matedock-2-docking-station/

Its the same dock that came with the computer. Video and audio works with windows.

Attached to a TV. Same exact setup works with Windows.

Comment: What audio devices can you find listed? Try `aplay -l` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/22031/what-are-my-audio-devices#22036) and add relevant output to your question. Have you had a look through the output of `dmesg` after unplugging and replugging the USB device - try `sudo dmesg | tail -100`?

Comment: Registered IR keymap rc-cec
rc rc0: DP-1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/rc/rc0
input: DP-1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/rc/rc0/input16
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5411, bcdDevice=61.30
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: Product: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected

Comment: AND

usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0411, bcdDevice=61.30
usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-4: Product: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Generic
hub 2-4:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-4:1.0: 4 ports detected

Comment: it's really weirds theres no sign of any HDMI audio anywhere, whatever I do, it's just not there. Must be like a driver issue or something like that. Have been googling hours and hours about this, but nothing. :(