# recordmydesktop CLI and external microphone

Tags: sound, usb, microphone

So... I am trying to solve this problem...

I want to record my desktop screen and also record my voice using an external mic.

I want to do it from CLI.

The **man recordmydesktop** indicates this:

```
--device SOUND_DEVICE
   Sound device(default hw:0,0 or /dev/dsp, depending on whether ALSA or OSS is used).
```

So then I am trying to find data about my USB mic. So I run **lsusb** and got:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17a0:0305 Samson Technologies Corp. GoMic compact condenser mic
```

But nothing looks liike `hw:0,0`.

Then I look in the more informative `lshw | grep -A 5 -B 4 Samson` and got:

```
*-usb:1
                   description: Audio device
                   product: Samson GoMic
                   vendor: Samson Technologies
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@2:3
                   version: 2.07
                   capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

Again no data. [Not much is found in the wiki either](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/RecordMyDesktop).

How do I find my sound device out?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22031/what-are-my-audio-devices) recommends using `aplay -l` command, in this case it outputs:

```
card 2: GoMic [Samson GoMic], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This means the device is **plughw:2,0** (not **0,0** in this case !) Apparently this means card 0, device 0.

Now it started recording