Sound issues with Ubuntu 24.04
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my PC. But I am facing issues with the audio that is not working. When I enter into the sound setting I cannot see my soundbox -- it only shows "Dummy output".
Please help me solving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

You probably want to provide make model. Maybe start with https://askubuntu.com/questions/22031/what-are-my-audio-devices

Does this answer your question? Persistent Dummy Output

I have resolved my Ubuntu 24.04 sound issue by following this YouTube tutorial. Very easy steps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTeBYuoat58

I experienced random sound freezes on my lenovo ideapad after fresh 24.04 install.
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [S24C550]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Just installed apt-get install pulseaudio and rebooted, issue gone.

Looks like this is a known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipewire/+bug/2063150
That post suggested blacklisting snd_soc_avs. (i.e. add this line: blacklist snd_soc_avs to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf)

Add this and do what to test whether it did anything? Any command required to restart some process? Is a reboot required?

This did not solve the issue for me (even after rebooting).

I had the same problem. Then I reinstalled it without the drivers and it worked normally. However, I tried to install the drivers again and it gave me the same problem again. I believe Ubuntu 24.04 is not identifying the drivers. For now I removed the third party drivers.

I am not a devloper, just a long time power user. No liability if this breaks you system.

Installing pulseaudio will probably break pipewire in 24.04.

After a fresh installation I ran
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
and then I ran a graphical tool called aptitude and reinstalled all packages.


